# Tuning SQL Server Query with function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

**Function :**

```
create function .[data_by_date_district](@rev_datetime datetime)
returns table
as
return
(
SELECT 
     ro.Region,[DATETIME],     
      sum(datain) 'datain',
      sum(dataout) 'dataout'
  FROM 
 data.inoutdata cr 
 join 
 structure.site ro  on
 ro.site = substring(replace([siteunqid],'**',''),1,LEN(siteunqid)-1)
 where  [DATETIME]  =@rev_datetime
 group by Region,[DATETIME]
);
```

***Executing this function with any date takes 00:00:00.***

**Now when I join this with another table it takes 4 sec (this table is 75 rows) :**

```
SELECT 
     Region,[DATETIME],datain,dataout,(cr.datain+cr.dataout) 'total',SP_GEOMETRY,MI_STYLE,MI_PRINX
  FROM 
  data.data_by_date_district(DATEADD(DAY,-1,cast(GETDATE() as DATE)) ) cr
  join 
  datamap.VectorMaps.REGION_BND db
  on db.Name =  cr.Region
```

*The first table has 1,700,000 rows of data which increases daily by 170,000 but other table has just 75 rows. Is there any way i could decrease the query time? The result of function is 75 rows.*

Comment: Please attach your execution plan.

Comment: @Devart Is image good because xml is too huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the body of the function straight in your query (replacing the function call)? Functions are not very good for performance, I think.

Something like that (sorry, formatting isn't best):

```
SELECT Region,
       [DATETIME],
       datain,
       dataout,
       (cr.datain + cr.dataout) 'total',
       SP_GEOMETRY,
       MI_STYLE,
       MI_PRINX
FROM (
    SELECT ro.Region,
           [DATETIME],
           SUM(datain) 'datain',
           SUM(dataout) 'dataout'
    FROM data.inoutdata cr
    JOIN structure.site ro ON ro.site = SUBSTRING(REPLACE([siteunqid], '**', ''), 1, LEN(siteunqid) - 1)
    WHERE [DATETIME] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    GROUP BY Region,
             [DATETIME]
) cr
JOIN datamap.VectorMaps.REGION_BND db ON db.Name = cr.Region
```

Comment: actually I am joining with this table to receive geometry column from it. I can't directly join it as it gives "Type geometry is not comparable it can't be used in group by clause"

Comment: okay that's cool it now takes 1 sec any way to tune it better because it's just 75 rows :( .

Comment: also i see that now clustered index seek cost is reduced from 75% to 46% on table inoutdata which is having action on 176133 rows.

Comment: Functions are only really good when applied in `SELECT` clause, I think. Otherwise they impact on performance.

Comment: I used CTE and the query ran in 00:00:00. It's fun. I don't know how this works but.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use common table expression instead of function to get your result set and replace function by cte in from clause. I hope this helps!

Comment: nice one Pratik CTE indeed helps